# PHP Onvif - GetSnapshotUri

Tags: php, onvif

I am using an opensource PHP library to communicate to a Onvif capable IP camera.
There was one function missing in the library, GetSnapshotUri which returns an URL where one can get a snapshot of the main stream.

Here is the source: http://pastebin.com/ekJa4D2h

Here is main page:

```
<?php

require 'class.ponvif.php';

$onvif = new Ponvif();
$onvif->setUsername('admin');
$onvif->setPassword('admin');
$onvif->setIPAddress('192.168.1.100');

try
{
    $onvif->initialize();
    $sources = $onvif->getSources();
    $profileToken = $sources[0][0]['profiletoken'];
    $uri = $onvif->media_GetSnapshotUri($profileToken);

    }
       catch(Exception $e)
  {
    print $e;
  }
?>
```

For some reason, the isFault function is true and i have no clue why.
The XML is valid, i checked it with Wireshark.
Does anybody have another camera to this if this works?
I have tried with 2 different camera's, Grandstream and Hikvision.
Also with ONVIF Device Manager v2.2.250 everything works as it should.
I know this is a long shot, but i have absolutely no clue.

Comment: I have wiresharked again, and i cannot see the program running a GetSnapshotUri at all.

Answer (score 0):

fix is here: http://pastebin.com/ryqxFjdR
mediaurl instead of getsnapshoturl in the function.